# ProtoBuf WCF "No Model instance has been assigned"

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, protobuf-net

I am getting this error:

No Model instance has been assigned to the ProtoOperationBehavior

I just used the WCF template application in Visual Studio to see if I could get it running.    How do I fix this error?

Code

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [ProtoBehavior()]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    [ProtoBehavior()]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
}


[DataContract]
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2)]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
```

app.config:

```
<services> 
<service name="ProtoBufService.Service1"> 
    <host> 
        <baseAddresses> 
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9086/ProtoBufService/Service1/" />
        </baseAddresses>
    </host> 
    <endpoint address="basic" 
        binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ProtoBufService.IService1" 
        behaviorConfiguration="protoEndpointBehavior">         
    </endpoint> 
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>     
</service> 
</services>
<extensions> 
    <behaviorExtensions> 
         <add name="protobuf" 
            type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, 
            protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.640, 
            Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67" />     
     </behaviorExtensions> 
</extensions>

<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="protoEndpointBehavior">
        <protobuf />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Comment: <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <!--<add name="protobuf" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.621, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67"/>-->
        <add name="protobuf" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net, Version=2.0.0.640, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

Comment: <services>
      <service name="ProtoBufService.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9086/ProtoBufService/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ProtoBufService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="protoEndpointBehavior">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

Comment: Which framework etc is this? And exactly which DLL of protobuf-net did you use? Nuget? Google code? If Google code: which variant? "Full"? Core only ?

Comment: I am using ProtoBuf 2.0.0.640".  The latest release posted on google code.

I tried using nuget.  That did not work.  I then tried to use the google code version (Core, net30 assembly), same error.

I am using IIS 7.5 with AppFabric on windows 7 x86 to test.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Framework 4.5 Full, not client.

Comment: My error.  I am not using IIS.  I created a console app and hosted the application using ServiceHost.  Yes, the app.config file is just like the web.config file.  I am using the same ProtoBuf assembly in all projects.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using nuget. That did not work.

I would love to hear more about what problems you had there

> I then tried to use the google code version (Core, net30 assembly), same error.

The "core only" library does not include the meta-programming layer - it is designed for use with pre-generated serialization assemblies. As such, there is no default model - one must always be provided.

The simplest "fix" here is simply to use the "full" build of the library; this has the meta-programming model as a default model.